# need to show antiderivative exist

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $U$ be a simply connected open set and $z_1,\dots, z_n$ be points of $U$ and let $U^*=U\setminus \{z_1,\dots,z_n\},z_i\in U$ Let $f$ be analytic on $U^*$. Let $\gamma_k$ be a small circle centered at $z_k$ and let $$a_k={1\over 2\pi i}\int_{\gamma_k} f(\xi)d\xi$$ let $$h(z)=f(z)-\sum a_k/(z-z_k)$$ we need to show there exist analytic function $H$ such that $H'=h$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: 1) what is the residue of $h$ at $z_j$?

2) Show that path integrals $\int_\Gamma h(z)\ dz$ in $U \backslash \{z_1,\ldots,z_n\}$ with the same endpoints are always equal.